# Loading floating numbers from txt file with python3 numpy

Tags: python, file, numpy, io

I am currently attempting to create a simple list of random floating numbers, save it in a text file and then loading the list of floating numbers with `numpy` using `numpy.loadtxt`.

For some reason whenever using `loadtxt` it states that the file is empty.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:891: UserWarning: loadtxt: Empty input file: "mydata1.txt"
warnings.warn('loadtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)

[ ]

class 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Here is a sample of the code:

```
import numpy
import scipy
import matplotlib
from random import random
import codecs

floats = list(random() for i in range (10))
fp = open('mydata1.txt','w')
for item in floats:
    str_item="{0:.5f}".format(item)
    fp.write("%s\n" % str_item )
fp.close

floats2 = numpy.loadtxt("mydata1.txt",dtype="str", delimiter="\n")
for myfloat in floats2:
    print("my floats is:",myfloat)
print(floats2)
print(type(floats2))
```

Comment: `fp.close` is not the same as `fp.close()`... Also, why don't you just make an array and use [`savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt)?

Comment: Hi @Mike Müller. This is more like an excersize to measure the capabilities of numpy and how it interacts with txt files. I previously tested arrays and tofile function which is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
fp = open('mydata1.txt','w')
for item in floats:
    str_item="{0:.5f}".format(item)
    fp.write("%s\n" % str_item )
fp.close
```

into:

```
with open('mydata1.txt','w') as fp:
    for item in floats:
        fp.write("{0:.5f}\n".format(item))
```

and it should work.

The `with open()` opens the file and closes it as soon as you dedent your code. 
Your `fp.close` does not close the file because your are missing the parenthesis. It should be: `fp.close()`. Per default, files are opened in buffered mode. So, if you don't flush or close the file no or not all data gets written to your file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help